# Restrict footer to take space only on last page in RDLC reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, rdlc

While working on RDLC reports with asp.net, am stuck in a case where i want footer to be on last page only.

[image]

I set footer propert "Show only on last page", but problem is that after doing this, footer is not appearing on any first pages but taking footer allocated space. I want to show footer only on last page of the Quatattion and footer will only take space on last page.
Is this possible ion RDLC reports?

Comment: I'm stuck on same problem. Is there any solution for this?